# Entity Framework Insert Into Table With AFTER INSERT Trigger

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, triggers

I am working on a Web API and Entity Framework 6 that is doing a "bulk" insert of under 500 records at any given time to a Microsoft SQL Server table. The DbContext.SaveChanges() method will insert all the records into a table in a couple seconds, so have no issues with that. However, when the method is called to insert the same number of records into the same table with a semi-extensive trigger attached to it, the process can take many minutes. The trigger has some calls to table joins and inserts into other tables and then deletes the newly inserted record.

I do not have much control of the table or the trigger, so I am looking for suggestions on how to improve performance. I made a suggestion to move the trigger to a stored procedure and have the trigger call the stored procedure, but I am uncertain if that will achieve any gains.

**EDIT**: As I understand my question was kind of generic, I will post some of my code in case it helps. The SQL is not mine, so I will see what I can actually post.

Here is the part of my Web API method that does the call to SaveChanges():

```
string[] stringArray = results[0].Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

var profileObjs = db.Set<T_ProfileStaging>();
foreach (var s in stringArray)
{

    string[] columns = s.Split(new[] {",", "\t"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
    if (columns.Length == 6)
    {
        T_ProfileStaging profileObj = new T_ProfileStaging();

        profileObj.CompanyCode = columns[0];
        profileObj.SubmittedBy = columns[1];
        profileObj.VersionName = columns[2];
        profileObj.DMName = columns[3];
        profileObj.Zone = columns[4];
        profileObj.DMCode = columns[5];
        profileObj.ProfileName = columns[6];
        profileObj.Advertiser = columns[7];
        profileObj.OriginalInsertDate = columns[8];

        profileObjs.Add(profileObj);
    }
}

try
{
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Ok();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "SQL Server Insert Exception");
}
```

Comment: SO Users have really nothing to provide you with.  You've given no c# nor SQL code so we have nothing to really do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load with SaveChanges() EF will send each row in a separate INSERT statement.  So if you have a statement trigger, it will run for each row.

To work around this you need either

- use a bulk load API from the client (instead of EF's SaveChanges()) using SqlBulkCopy directly, or one of the many EF extensions that wrap it.

or

- Configure EF to insert into a different table and then INSERT ... SELECT into the target table